# Laravel | Trying to send data using URL

Tags: laravel

In Laravel, I'm trying to send Data using URL for an e-payment need.

The code in controller in charge is :

```
$home_url = $URL . '/forward_Data.php?URL='.$URL.'&ORDER_ID='.$ORDER_ID.'&REFERENCE_ID='.$REFERENCE_ID.'&TRACK_ID='.$TRACK_ID;
```

my forward_data.php path is : `App\xxx\forward_data.php`

forward_data.php full code given by the plateforme is ( with out namespace define) :

```
<form id="redirectForm" action="<?php echo $_GET['URL']; ?>" method="post" name="myform">
  <input type="hidden" name="ORDER_ID" value="<?php echo $_GET['ORDER_ID']; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="REFERENCE_ID" value="<?php echo $_GET['REFERENCE_ID']; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="TRACK_ID" value="<?php echo $_GET['TRACK_ID']; ?>"/>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
   document.getElementById("redirectForm").submit();
</script>
```

Function works fine except $home_url **(the part when you send data to the plateform and redirection)** , I'm getting an 404 not found error In console the request URL is :

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/send/forward_Data.php?FPAY_URL=https://pay/sandbox/home_card2&ORDER_ID=xx&REFERENCE_ID=xx&TRACK_ID=xx

Method : Get 
Staut code : 404
```

Route :

```
Route::get('/send', 'SendController@Send');
```

**Processus description :**

Call Function1 to collect `$data`, then, executing Function2 to validate `$data`and then execute `$home_url`

My issue is this part : `'forward_Data.php?URL='` i have no idea how to define/use forward_Data.php into the URL.

**Expectation :**  :

Sending OrderID & ReferenceID with Redirecting to pay plateforme with

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

First: you have to create a specific route for your function.

```
Route::get('/send/forward_data', 'SendController@SendForwardData');
```

SendController (is your file .php)
SendForrwardData (is your method)

then, your route would be:

```
$home_url = $URL . '/forward_data?FPAY_URL='.$FPAY_URL.'&ORDER_ID='.$ORDER_ID.'&REFERENCE_ID='.$REFERENCE_ID.'&TRACK_ID='.$TRACK_ID;
```

Into your sendController, you will define specific funtion you want, using `$request->yourvars`

If you want to use your fordward_Data.php, you will have to set into controller folder, and create a new route:

```
Route::get('/send/forward_data', 'fordward_Data@data');
```

Comment: Thank you sir for ur interest, but still, I'm not getting it. 
my $home_url is inside  a function in a class named XX. The class is in APP\XX\XX.php 

The class is called in XController which i call using my rouge GET /Send 

How to configurate the new route /send/forward_data ?  
THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Route::get('/send/{data}', 'SendController@Send');
```

in SendController

```
public function Send($data)
    {

      //$data contains url data 

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but my $home_url is not in Send Function. It's inside a class named X in APP\XX\XX.php